# "brake the rules" vs "break the rules"

Tags: expressions, synonyms

In a shop I have found a T-shirt with the sentence: "Brake the rules" (not "Break the rules"). Is it correct?

Comment: Considering that the media on which it is written is often used to portray some short one-liner joke, I feel safe in assuming that it is meant to be a phonemic idiom of sorts.

By chance, did the T-shirt have a picture of a car or automobile on it? "Brake" would refer both to break/sever (the correct word) and also the brakes/stopping mechanisms of an automobile.

Comment: It is probably a pun!

Comment: Don't buy this shirt because most of the people will not understand it. And you will look like a...

Comment: actually, since the T-shirt is sold in Italy, I am tempted to believe in a mistake.

Answer (score 36):

It's a pun on *break*.

The slogan exhorts the reader to "Break the rules," and to make the point it does just that itself, by breaking the rule about how to spell *break*.

Comment: The technical English term for jokes of this sort is "unfunny."

Comment: @mxyzplk It's funny enough, IMO. People's opinions will differ.

Comment: A better variant of the same of joke: [Describe yourself in three words...](https://pbs.twimg.com/media/B0AemkSCYAASfJ1.jpg:large)

Comment: Brake the rules (of the English language!)

Comment: @user568458 Related from the #FiveWordTechHorrors a year ago: [Off by one error](https://twitter.com/izs/status/410181915103080448) and [fixed the off by one error](https://twitter.com/izs/status/410181978298675200)